# What's the purpose of same sentences with and without plural forms?

Tags: support, closed-questions, localization, email-notification, plurals

There're a couple of the same sentences in traducir.win:

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If that question doesn’t answer your issue, edit your question to highlight the difference between the associated question and yours. If edited, your question will be reviewed and might be reopened. $br$$br$ **Find out more about duplicates and why your question has been closed.**

#### without plural forms:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18340

#### with plural forms:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18221
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18222
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18223

What's the purpose of simultaneous existence for both? Are plural forms actually used in email notifications when multiple questions become closed?

Comment: I don't know how to navigate Traducir, but the string does vary, just not in the bold part. If you have multiple duplicates, "a similar question" (etc.) is plural. This is shown on your own closed duplicate questions.

Comment: @Laurel this is fully covered by sentences with plural forms (one,few,many). My question about the existence of the first type sentence (without plural forms at all). Looks like the first sentence was ... the first, and later people realized that plurals are needed, but first type was forgotten to delete.